# Trying to clear cell based on content of another cell, dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched for day for a solution. I have a schedule that I make on a daily basis. The schedule will have a varying number of rows depending on how busy I am but the columns are constant.

For the most part I can do what I need by simply recording a macro.

The issue is that I need to clear the contents of a cell when a condition is met in another cell on the same row. Specifically, if there is a letter L in a given row on column H than I need to clear the contents of the cell in column B on the same row.

I have found similar questions with answers but they all affected the content of static cells.

I have tried several variations of the following:

```
Sub mdlabkill()

Dim LastRow As Long

Dim x As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To LastRow

    If Cells(x, 5).Value = L Then Range(Cells(x, 2)).ClearContent

    Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post some of your data and picture of your worksheet?

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and watch VBA complain about variable `L` not being defined. If you mean to compare against a string literal, surround `L` in quotes then: `"L"` is a string literal, `L` is a variable that you haven't declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you may try this code:

```
Sub mdlabkill()
Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To LastRow                    'x = 1 indicates your first data is located in row 1
    If Cells(x, "H").Value = "L" Then   'Or Cells(x, 7) = "L"
        Cells(x, "B").ClearContents     'Or .Clear to delete all the formats in the cell
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect that you understood what I was asking for because that code worked perfectly. Thank you